# How to use 'select' properly in jq?

Tags: select, jq

Given a json like this:

```
{

    "project" : [
        {
            "name" : "dungeon master",
            "date" : "2022-05-11T16:07:29.000Z",
            "status" : "active"
        },
        {
            "name" : "great gatsby",
            "date" : "2023-04-20T19:49:26.000Z",
            "status" : "active"
        },
        {
            "name" : "hundred years",
            "date" : "2022-11-29T23:37:29.000Z",
            "status" : "active"
        },
        {
            "name" : "passage to india",
            "date" : "2022-11-22T04:16:50.000Z",
            "status" : "active"
        }      
   
    ]
}
```

to get the key **'name'** that has the string **'ma'**, I build up the jq using this chain of thought step by step:

```
.project[] | .name |contains("ma")
>>true
false
false
false

.project[] | select( .name |contains("ma"))
>>{
  "name": "dungeon master",
  "date": "2022-05-11T16:07:29.000Z",
  "status": "active"
}

.project[] | select( .name |contains("ma")) |.name
>> "dungeon master"
#success
```

but if I use the abbreviation way, it doesn't work:

```
.project[].name |contains("ma")
>>true
false
false
false

select(.project[].name |contains("ma"))
>>get back whole json 

select(.project[].name |contains("ma"))|.name 
>> null
```

Using **'select'** on the abbreviation **'.array[].key'** seems having totally different output. I think I missed some important understanding about jq here.

My questions:

1. why `select(.project[].name |contains("ma"))|.name` doesn't work ? what is the wrong understanding behind that usage ?
2. what is the different concept between `.array[].key` and `.array[] | .key` is wrong that cause the above not working ?

Comment: select works on lists, if you start your filter as select, it receives an object, not a list, so there's nothing to filter. Since your select resolves to true, you get the whole json back.

Comment: You however don't need the `| .name` in your last example, `.project[] | select(.name | contains("ma")).name` works fine.

Comment: @0stone0 `select` works on input of any type. It reproduces it on the condition given, regardless of it being a list or not. Try `{a:(1,2,3)} | select(.a % 2 == 1)` which produces two objects with no lists involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a common misconception that `select` would descend into the input structure, then "select from" those subordinate items the ones matching a condition, and return them. This notion probably comes from the function's name, for which "filter" or "asserting" could have been a better choice, because the structures involved in the evaluation of the condition, and the ones returned if the condition was met, are actually in no way related. In fact, while the former may descend arbitrarily deep (including not at all, or using variables with "external" values), the latter is always either the entire, unaltered input (if the condition was met), or nothing (in the sense of no output at all, just like with `empty`). Moreover, if the condition (just like with the input context) is a stream of values, the output, if produced, is still the input value but accordingly multiplied into a stream of values as well (actually, the single-value case is no exception to that, if you consider it being a stream of just one value). That said, let's answer your questions:

> 1. why `select(.project[].name |contains("ma"))|.name` doesn't work ? what is the wrong understanding behind that usage ?

Starting with the top-level as the current context, `select` will either reproduce it, or have no output at all, depending on the boolean evaluation of the condition. Then, at `|`, output that is present becomes the new (yet same) context, and is taken as input for `.name`, which either produces the value of that field, or `null` if there was no field of that name, or an error if the input was neither an object nor `null` itself.

Given your sample data, the object `{"project": …}`, as context, `.project[].name | contains("ma")` produces `true` exactly once, so `select` reproduces its input, also once. However, as this object does not have a field called `name`, `.name` produces `null`, also once.

As an exercise, try changing either the string values present in the fields, or the substring searched for, so that more than one item matches, and you will get as many `null` outputs - and likewise no output if there is no match.

Now, instead of trying to extract `.name` from there, you could, of course, descend again to its actual location, but at this point you have lost the instances that conveyed where the condition was met. With your successful approach, `.project[] | select( .name |contains("ma")) |.name`, you

- `.project[]`: descended into the array items, producing a stream of (in this case: four) objects as the new contexts,
- `select( .name |contains("ma"))`: reproduced the same objects if and only if their `name` field's value contained the substring given (here: one object makes it)
- `.name`: extract the desired value in the right context.

To avoid code duplication, you could even pull the extraction of `.name` out of, i.e. before the condition, making it already the context for `select` and the final output:

```bash
jq -r '.project[].name | select(contains("ma"))'
```

```
dungeon master
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/vdwmhyGdZ05)

---

> 2. what is the different concept between `.array[].key` and `.array[] | .key` is wrong that cause the above not working ?

As described above, `|` changes the context. If you had `.array[].key1, .key2`, `.key2` would be evaluated in the same context as `.array[].key1`. With `.array[] | .key1, .key2`, both keys are evaluated in the same context of `.array[]` (which is a stream of probably multiple items).

Comment: Amazing answer. Your explanation totally change my understand on **select**. I have read this few days and brainstorm a lot with it. I tried your exercise, and change my condition to `.project[].name|contains("d")` and it returns 3 true, and when I use it with `select(.project[].name |contains("d"))` , I now get back 3 whole json instead of 1! 

Am I right to say that, **select** doesn't care how deep level of json we put in the boolean condition of **select()**,it will always return the input level we pass to it(aka the object level before the pipe of **select**)?

Comment: @sylye Yes. The output of `select`, if produced, can never be different from its input. If there are multiple inputs (a stream), this is true individually for each of the inputs, i.e. one input may be produced, another one may be swallowed. The number of times the output is produced based on one input, however, may be other than one (namely if the condition itself evaluated to a stream of multiple `true` values). But the content (structure, nesting, values, etc.) is never changed, it can only "pass through" in its entirety, i.e. each output item is always identical to (one of) the input items.

Comment: thanks for the reply. May I know do you have any good recommend of any good **books/website** that I could get such deep and pedagogical explain on how jq works? because I tried to learn jq many years but I always stumble into such similar wrong perception of how fundamentally jq behave. I **searched a long time** but couldn't find a good book on it.

Comment: @sylye I don't know of any books, but as for online resources (apart from the [manual](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/), obviously), I found studying how the the [builtin functions are implemented in jq itself](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq) quite educative. There's also the [jq Wiki](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/wiki), most notably including a [jq Language Description](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/wiki/jq-Language-Description) and the [jq Cookbook](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/wiki/Cookbook).

Comment: Thanks so much of the tips! I just tried out the link you provided, the buitin.jq really give a good insight on the internal logic on how they works, appreciated that so much ! Will be going through the other 3 links as well :)

Answer (score 2):

`select` either lets through a value, or filters it out. But it does not change the value in any way.

---

```
{ "project": [ {…},{…},{…},{…} ] } | select( .project[].name | contains( "ma" ) )
```

Only one value is passed to `select`: `{ "project" : [ ... ] }`. It will either return this value or return nothing. This isn't what you want. You don't want the entire structure, but a single project. So this is wrong no matter what's inside the `select`.

---

```
{ "project": [ {…},{…},{…},{…} ] } | .project[] | select( .name | contains( "ma" ) )
```

`select` is called four times, one for each of the projects (`{…}`). Each time, it will either return the project, or nothing. So you'll end up with zero to four projects. This is what you want.

---

Think of `select` as the `grep` command line utility.

```
$ cat file
foo
bar
baz

$ grep a file
bar
baz

$ cat file.json
"foo"
"bar"
"baz"

$ jq 'select( contains( "a" ) )' file.json
"bar"
"baz"

$ cat file2.json
[ "foo", "bar", "baz" ]

$ jq '.[] | select( contains( "a" ) )' file2.json
"bar"
"baz"
```

`select` simply works with values instead of lines.